# Ruby - Why Thread doesn't respect method put?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

The following code throw messages without putting them with line break.

```
threads = []
counter = 1000
counter.times do
     threads << Thread.new do 
        puts "This is a line."
        sleep 1
     end
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

The result is

```
This is a line. This is a line

This is a line.
This is a line.

and so on...
```

Is there anyway to print the result line in a tidier way?

Comment: Is this jruby? I don't think you get this behavior with MRI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts` works internally by printing its argument, then by printing a newline. Sometimes, the thread gets interrupted between the two operations, resulting in the behavior you're seeing. You could instead say:

```
 print "This is a line.\n"
```

...which would write the entire string -- including newline -- in a single operation.